How to group all the values of a column into a one single row as a list corresponding to a single category in a tabular visual in Power BI
P.S : I'm a beginner to POWER BI
I have a table visual in my power bi dashboard that looks like this right now:



Category
Serial No
Location
Details




Books
1111154
West
A1


Books
1111154
West
A2


Books
1111154
West
A3


Pens
1234344
West
B1


Pens
1234344
West
B2


Pens
1234344
West
B3


Pens
1234344
West
B4


Clips
2444434
East
C1


Clips
2444434
East
C2



How do I make this table look like this? :

I tried concatenatex functions etc but it didn't give the result I wanted.

You need a calculated column where you can use CONCATENATEX with UNICHAR(10) as '/n' if you want to have each value in a seperate line and RANKX to include an index number before each value in the concatenated list, specifically for each unique combination of Serial No, Category, and Location :
ConcatenatedDetails = 
CONCATENATEX(
    FILTER(
        YourTable,
        YourTable[Serial No] = EARLIER(YourTable[Serial No]) &&
        YourTable[Category] = EARLIER(YourTable[Category]) &&
        YourTable[Location] = EARLIER(YourTable[Location])
    ),
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            YourTable,
            YourTable[Serial No] = EARLIER(YourTable[Serial No]) &&
            YourTable[Category] = EARLIER(YourTable[Category]) &&
            YourTable[Location] = EARLIER(YourTable[Location])
        ),
        YourTable[Details],
        ,
        ASC
    ) & ". " & YourTable[Details], 
    UNICHAR(10)
)



Supplemental answer to @Amira's. If you wanted it as a Measure:
All Details = 
  var result =
    CONCATENATEX(
      'YourTable',
      RANKX('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Details], ,ASC) & ". " & 'YourTable'[Details],
      UNICHAR(10)
    )
  RETURN IF(ISINSCOPE(YourTable[Category]), result)

